# proving equivalence of simple inequalities

Tags: inequality

I want to show and claim following equations hold.

P is positive definite,
$$
(1)\qquad x^T\cdot P\cdot x > 1 \implies x^T\cdot P\cdot x + e \gt 1, \text{ for all } e > 0\\ 
(2)\qquad x^T\cdot P\cdot x + e > 1 \text{ for all } e>0 \implies x^T\cdot P\cdot x > 1 \\
$$

For me (1) equivalence seems to be working.
However, I am not confident whether (2) is okay.

I found some book uses the logic that $g(x) + e > f(x)$ for $e > 0$ implies $g(x) > f(x)$. Similar to the logic from the book, do you think that I can remove "$e$" in (2) equation and claim that both equations are equivalent?

Can anyone validate this equivalence and provide comments on this?

Comment: In each part, should that be "For all $e$ such that $e>0$"? And what is $a$ in that next-to-last paragraph?

Comment: Yes, each part for all e such that e > 0. sorry for confusion. I changed variable a into e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your statement (1) is true.** Let the real number $x^T\cdot P\cdot x$ be called $p$. Then the statement is
$$p>1 \text{ and } e>0 \implies p+e>1$$

which is true by the addition postulate of real inequalities.

**Your statement (2) is not true.** Consider

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
  P = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$p=x^T\cdot P\cdot x=1$$

So if $e>0$ then $p+e>1$ but we do not have $p>1$.

However, you can modify statement (2) to the true statement

$$x^T\cdot P\cdot x + e \gt 1 \text{ for all } e>0 \implies x^T\cdot P\cdot x \ge 1$$

This is a basic property of the real numbers, proved early in an analysis class. Let me know if you need a proof of that statement.

Comment: Thank you for comments. As your example, we do not have p > 1. but if we have x = [2; 0], then p > 1. Do you think that I can say there exists x and P, such that xT⋅P⋅x>1? In addition, can you explain me why >= holds?

Comment: Yes. If $x^T\cdot P\cdot x=p$ then $(rx)^T\cdot P\cdot (rx)=pr^2$. Just take real number $r$ large enough, then $rx$ satisfies your inequality.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you think you can explain me xT⋅P⋅x+e>1 for all e>0⟹xT⋅P⋅x≥1? I do not understand why we have equality there..